# How can I insert a row after the row that is now selected in a sorted table

Tags: sorting, insert, jtable

this is more or less a duplicate of the ones below:

[How can i sort java JTable with an empty Row and force the Empty row always be last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316563/how-can-i-sort-java-jtable-with-an-empty-row-and-force-the-empty-row-always-be-la)

http://www.java.net/node/645655

the only difference is that i would like to insert the new row after the row that is currently selected. the default behavior of DefaultRowSorter would sort immediately when the row is inserted, while what i need is to turn off sorting temporarily so that i could insert the row in a position that i specified, not a position from the sorter

i noticed that there were 2 links provided in [How can i sort java JTable with an empty Row and force the Empty row always be last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316563/how-can-i-sort-java-jtable-with-an-empty-row-and-force-the-empty-row-always-be-la), but they are not valid anymore, that's why i created this new question.

Answer (score 0):

I copied completely DefaultRowSorter and TableRowSorter from JDK and changed insertInOrder() like below and it seems now working as I expected.

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
if(sortOnInsert)
{
    index = Arrays.binarySearch(current, toAdd.get(i));
    if (index < 0) {
        index = -1 - index;
    }
}
else
{
    Row rowBeforeAdd = new Row(this, toAdd.get(i).modelIndex - 1);
    index = Arrays.binarySearch(current, rowBeforeAdd);
    if (index < 0) {
        index = viewToModel.length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        index += 1;
    }
}
```