# How to display empty rows in a JTable and be able to sort the empty rows to always appear at bottom

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with some data and some empty rows. 
The table is constructed with a table model with 5 rows of data. But I have it showing and additional 6 empty rows below the 5 filled rows by overloading the `getRowCount()` to return 11 in the table model.

However when I do a sort, the empty rows will appear at the top of the table. I would like the empty rows to always show at the bottom of the table.

What is the best way of doing this without creating a second table with empty rows tacked on below the one that is sort-able?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution via: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316563/how-can-i-sort-java-jtable-with-an-empty-row-and-force-the-empty-row-always-be-last Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`TableRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) that does the sorting you need, and register it as the sorter using [`JTable.setRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter-javax.swing.RowSorter-).

This will involve creating a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that always has the empty rows be greater than non-empty rows based on some or all fields. This will have to take the [`SortOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SortOrder.html) into account if you want to have the empty rows appear at the bottom even if you reverse the sort order. You can get the ordering by [`RowSorter.getSortKeys`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#getSortKeys--).

Answer (score 0):

```
The call to getSortKeys().get() must use 0 (i.e. the main sort key) and not column:

boolean ascending = getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING;
If the user clicks, for example, over the column number 12 or 7, you want the first sort key (there will be 3 at most, if the user clicked before over other columns, to perform multi column sort). This sort key will have two attributes:

Sort Order (ASCENDING, DESCENDING, UNORDERED)
getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder()
Column Index (12 or 7, for example)
getSortKeys().get(0).getColumn()
```